# Are Active Directory GUID strings fine to compare case insensitively?

Tags: active-directory, guid, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I couldn't find this documented, so I'm wondering if it matters...

With Active Directory you may need to compare app ids, object ids etc to know ones for authorization purposes. Since app ids and object ids are just randomly generated GUIDs that are first generated in one place, and then copied around to everywhere else that they are needed, I don't see a good reason that the case of these identifiers would ever change or vary. So I would guess that its 'fine' to do case sensitive comparison of them most of the time.

But GUIDs are generally parsed case insensitively, so logically it seems like it should also be fine to do case-insensitive comparison too. And that would be the most widely compatible approach.

So conclusion is... it doesn't really matter... but case-insensitive should be preferred right? If not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the covers, a GUID (or [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)) is a 128-bit number. The letters in the text representation are not actually letters: they are numbers in base 16, where A-F comes after 9. So case makes no difference at all.

If you will be comparing string representations, then there is no harm in doing a case-insentive comparison. However, even better (and slightly faster) is to compare the actual numerical value. For example, .NET has the [`Guid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid?view=netframework-4.8) struct, where [the equality operator](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/guid.cs,1108) compares each byte in the value.